# Laravel nullable validation fails on email

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a paypal email field, which is not required, so can be left empty. I send a formdata with null value, but validation fails.

My validation is:

```
'paypal_email'=>'nullable|email',
```

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What's the failed validation

Comment: paypal_email: ["The paypal email must be a valid email address."]

Comment: This is weird, I think this should have worked perfectly!

Comment: Can you post the request data

Comment: "------WebKitFormBoundaryBX4UrEkZDZctN1Ee
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

nicholaus86@yahoo.com
------WebKitFormBoundaryBX4UrEkZDZctN1Ee
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="paypal_email"

null
"

Comment: What version of Laravel?

Comment: @Don'tPanic 5.4

Comment: weird, it should work. Just try to remove 'nullable' from validation array and leave it empty when you submit the form. By default laravel converts empty strings to null... so technically you don't need to define it again. If the "The paypal email must be a valid email address." messages shows up it means there's something in his value (maybe "null") as a string or something else

Comment: @bLuke formdata only sends strings and images, so it was sending null as string!

Answer (score 1):

Formdata was sending string "null" thats why failed.